# Angular multi-language input field for entering text in multiple languages

Tags: html, angular, internationalization, ngx-translate, angular12

I am working on a multi-language web application using Angular 12 and ASP.NET Core 6 for the backend. For the most part, all interactions with the backend are simple CRUD operations. In many cases, the entities being used in the application have properties (such as names) which have different values depending on the (browser) language. This means that, depending on the language of the frontend, a different value should be displayed for such properties. In order to do this, the backend returns such properties as a dictionary where they key is the language and the value is the translation for the property in the specific language. Here is an example:

```
 id: 1,
      name: {
        en: "Apple",
        de: "Apfel",
      },
...
```

The frontend then uses the browser language to decide which translation should be displayed. If there is no translation for the browser language, the english translation will be used. For static text, such as labels of controls, headlines etc., ngx-translate is used.

This approach already works perfectly fine, but so far there is no way to allow the user to specify multiple translations when a new entity is created via the frontend. Instead, the property is entered via a mat-form-field like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>{{ "translations.name" | translate }}</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="name" />
  <mat-error
    *ngIf="createForm.hasError('required', 'name')"
    [innerHtml]="'translations.errors.required' | translate | markdown"
  ></mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

The entered text is then added to the name dictionary with the current browser language as key.

What I am now looking for is a way to replace this standard input field with something that supports entering multiple strings for different languages. I'd prefer this input field to be similar to the normal text input field but with an additional button/icon that opens a new dialog where multiple translations can be entered for different languages (e.g. in a table). Does such a control already exist, or is this something I would have to implement myself?

Comment: It's something you're going to have to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something you would implement yourself, however, you can use a 3rd-party library that supports multi-languages input such as [Angular Formly](https://formly.dev/).

And here is their related example that you can use or take a look at how it's implemented to implement something similar using `ngx-translate`:

https://formly.dev/examples/advanced/i18n